# Copy from Console2 to Clipboard

Tags: windows, unix, powershell, terminal, console2

I'm connected to a EC2 (Ubuntu) instance via SSH using the [Console2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx) (I can connect using the default Windows terminal if is the case). And I need to copy a SSH key to the clipboard so a I can paste in the deploy keys of Bitbucket, how to copy it to the Windows clipboard? Thank you.

Comment: Possibly other answers at https://superuser.com/questions/132711/how-to-copy-text-from-console2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Windows 8.1 and below:**

1. Right click the terminal and select mark
2. Hold shift to select your text you want to copy
3. Hit the enter key on your keyboard to copy the text

**Windows 10 and up:**

You can now hold down `shift` and then `Ctrl`+`C` to copy text.

Answer (score 1):

Done with the PowerShell!
I could select the characters, right-click on the window title, then Edit -> Copy!
And I think that the hotkey is Enter